# Python3 MySQL Drivers

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Recently, I switched to Python 3 (3.1 on a FreeBSD system), and i would like to work with MySQL databases.

- First i tried to use [pymysql3-0.4](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/), but it failed when i used SUM in my query with this error: 
  , TypeError("Cannot convert b'46691486' to Decimal",))
- Then i tried [oursql-0.9.2](https://launchpad.net/oursql/py3k), but it seems it has no unix socket support (the documentation write otherwise but it doesn't recognize the socket protocol.)
- Last i decided to give a chance to mypysql-0.5.5 but the installation is failed.

Could you recommend me a properly working MySQL driver for Python 3, or at least solve one of these problems? I would be very greatfull.

Comment: It would help to see the code that generated the TypeError. There could be reasons other than the driver.

Comment: `conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',  user='test', passw='psw1', db='test', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock')
cur = conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT SUM(data) FROM table WHERE date >= %d GROUP BY name" % time
cur.execute(query)`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processo.py", line 45<br/>
    cur.execute("SELECT SUM(data) FROM `table` WHERE date >= %d GROUP BY name" % time)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 108, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 182, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise Error(errorclass, errorvalue)
pymysql.err.Error: (<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError("Cannot convert b'146120235' to Decimal",))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oursql [documentation](http://packages.python.org/oursql/api.html) is a little tricky. :$ There is a list of Connection's parameters, but it doesn't contain the unix_socket parameter. If i set that and the the protocol parameter the whole thing is just work fine :)

If someone has trouble with inserting (get _statment charset AttributeError): https://bugs.launchpad.net/oursql/+bug/669184 change the lines in oursql.c with the code in the report, and rebuild it. (it will be fixed in 0.9.3)